# typescript error - Types of property 'headers' are incompatible

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm having a problem with my Angular application. I get a typescript error when I try to do an `http` call.

This is the error output:

> [09:36:28]  typescript: C:/xampp/htdocs/project x/anonymous-social/src/pages/home/home.ts, line: 184
>               Argument of type '{ headers: HttpHeaders; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RequestOptionsArgs'.
>               Types of property 'headers' are incompatible. Type 'HttpHeaders' is not assignable to type 'Headers'.
>               Property 'forEach' is missing in type 'HttpHeaders'.
>
> L183:  this.http.post(url, JSON.stringify(payload),
>
> L184:  {headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'})})
>
> L185:  .map((res:Response) => {

I'm not entirely sure what it doesn't like..

This is my actual code:

I'm loading in both `http` and `/common/http`

```
import { HttpHeaders } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Http, Response } from "@angular/http";
```

and then in the constructor:

```
private http: Http,
```

and then finally my js:

```
getCall(url, payload, text) {
  this.http.post(url, JSON.stringify(payload),
  {headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'})})
  .map((res:Response) => {
    console.log(res)
})
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I set up the headers, I'm using `Headers`, not `HttpHeaders`:

```
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from "@angular/http";

// ...

const headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8' });
const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

// ...
```